# Type hint for a matplotlib color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, type-hinting

I'm type-hinting functions in Python, and not sure what type a matplotlib color should be. I have a function like this:

```
def plot_my_thing(data: np.ndarray, color: ???):
    # function def here
```

What should the type be in `???`, when it is meant to be a matplotlib color that you can feed into `plt.plot()` for the type hint? Right now I'm planning to just use `Any`.

I've searched and not found an answer. There are some discussions at GitHub about it:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21505

But that seems like a package-specific problem, though I may not be understanding it.

Comment: It can be both `str` and `matplotlib.colors`

Comment: Does anything on this page count as a `matplotlib.colors` instance: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html   E.g., does a `str` like `red` count as a `matplotlib.colors` instance?

Comment: `str` can be name colors or hex represantation of colors such as `#ffffff`. BTW I forgot that color can be tuple of floats and integers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, I think the correct answer is: *there is no type for `matplotlib.colors`*. It's a `module`, and from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colors_api.html), it's:

> A module for converting numbers or **color arguments** to *RGB* or *RGBA*.

So regardless of what you set as a type-hint, it *has* to do the conversion. There is no benefit specifying `str` or `matplotlib.colors`, if you do not supply correct format, it throws an error from `colors.py` module anyway.

Your origianal choice `Any` is cleaner than `str` or `matplotlib.colors`.

```py
from typing import Any
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_my_thing(colors: Any, fig):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
    y = np.sin(x)
    A = 1.0
    for c in colors:
        plt.plot(x, A * y, c=c)
        A *= 0.9
    plt.savefig(fig)


plot_my_thing(["C1", "red", (0.1, 0.2, 0.5), '#0f0f0f80', '#aabbcc',
               '0.8', 'g', 'aquamarine', 'xkcd:sky blue', 'tab:blue'], "mygraph.png")

plot_my_thing(matplotlib.colors.CSS4_COLORS, "mygraph2.png")
```

output:

`mygraph.png`
[image: mygraph.png]

`mygraph2.png`
[image: mygraph.png]

Comment: It would be useful if they made a class for purposes of type hinting, but as it stands the type is so disjunctive it does seem `Any` might be the right choice. I haven't actually tested `matplotlib.colors` which was suggested in a comment above. You are right, it is a module not a Class, so it probably shouldn't work. :)